# Subscriptions.list order: unread option - how to filter for video upload activity?

Tags: youtube-api

Using YouTube Data API v3, I am trying to get a list of YouTube video-uploads by channels I subscribed to, ordered by video upload time, grouped by channel, sorted by channels with latest uploads first.

The Subscriptions.list method gets me the results sorted by order of activities `{ order: unread }` by channel. But this may include all activities like rating, creating playlists, etc. I am interested in the video upload by channel activity only. Is there anyway I can get this using API?

Comment: Unfortunately the API is fairly limited... the only way I got this working is by filtering for `snippet.type = "upload"` or checking if `contentDetails.upload` exists

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  ['youtube.channel.list'](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?hl=fr) with the parameters: '*part=contentDetails*'
The 'part' parameter specifies a comma separated list of one or more channel resource properties that the API response will include.

Also, include *'items[]'*. 'items' parameter will give you the list of channels that match the request criteria.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem mentioned in the question